# Pandas: get values from columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have following dataframe in pandas:

```
               US46434V7617  US3160928731  US4642865251
2021-07-20     13.741297     53.793367    104.151499
```

How can I convert this to a dict with as keys the columns and as values the values of the columns. For example:

```
[{'US46434V7617': 13.741297048948578, 'US3160928731': 53.7933674972021, 'US4642865251': 104.15149908700006}]
```

Comment: What about the index . . . are you looking for `df.to_dict(orient='index')`? or do you want `orient='records'`

Comment: Prior to your edit, note that what you wanted to obtain was a [set](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp) of 3 [dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). Such object does not exist in python since dictionaries are [unhashable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957396/why-dict-objects-are-unhashable-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

You can use df.to_dict with orient='records':

```
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

This will give you a list of dictionaries, one for each row. By the way, the structure you provided in the question is not valid, it must be a list of dictionaries or a dictionary with key:value pairs